# Create Seed Data for Analytics Ahoy gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ahoy

I want to create some seed data for [Ahoy Analytics Gem](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) for a demo

How would I simulate page visits but also alter the date recorded in the db to simulate past visitor data?

Any help is appreciated Thanks

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  I'm trying to create a number of events in `seeds.rb` without any luck - I'm stuck on the event failing to save due to the visit missing.  Any chance you found a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

could simulate in part with capybara, and could also alter value in capybara routine

also, https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/ in case that may be of interest

Answer (score 0):

I created my `Ahoy::Visits` and `Ahoy::Events` manually.

```
# use the Faker gem for fake data

request = OpenStruct.new(
  params: { },
  referer: Faker::Internet.url,
  remote_ip: Faker::Internet.public_ip_v4_address,
  user_agent: Faker::Internet.user_agent,
  original_url: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url,
)

visit_properties = Ahoy::VisitProperties.new(request, api: nil)
properties = visit_properties.generate.select { |_, v| v }

example_visit = Ahoy::Visit.create!(properties.merge(
  visit_token: SecureRandom.uuid,
  visitor_token: SecureRandom.uuid,
  started_at: Time.current
))

example_event = Ahoy::Event.create!(
  visit: example_visit,
  name: 'example_event',
  properties: 'example properties',
  time: Time.current
)
```